# Excel Insert Script with optional columns SQL server 2004

Tags: sql, excel

I have a very large excel document that I need to insert into a database. So I created an excel script and applied it to all the columns.

```
="INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Webteam_BSDOM_Record] (FlyerName, OrganizationName, MaterialStatus, OrganizationStatus, Audience, DOMType, DeliveryMethod, Link, ApprovalDate, CreatedDate, CreatedByUser )
 VALUES ('" & A7 & "','" & B7 & "','" & C7 & "','" &D7& "','" &E7& "','" &F7&"', '" &G7&"', " &H7&"," &I7&"," &I7&", 2);"
```

So far so good. I copy all the generated inserts into a query which is where I notice my problem. Some of my columns are optional, so in my query I will sometimes get something like this

```
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Webteam_BSDOM_Record] (FlyerName, OrganizationName, MaterialStatus, OrganizationStatus, Audience, DOMType, DeliveryMethod, Link, ApprovalDate, CreatedDate, CreatedByUser )
VALUES ('6th Toronto Scout Group ','Scouts Canada','Approved','Non-Profit Organization','SELECT ELEMENTARY AND SECONDARY SCHOOLS Boy Scouts of Canada','After-School Activities', 'Vendor - Hand Delivery',  ,42264,42264, 2);
```

Notice the

```
,  ,
```

This causes an error in my insert. How can I edit my original excel script to lose a comma whenever a column is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with some value.  Perhaps `NULL` will do:

```
" & iff(isblank(H7), "NULL", H7)&"
```

Comment: @ortz3 . . . That wouldn't be "empty".  That would be a string value with one space.  You can expand the logic to `" & iff(isblank(H7) or len(substitute(H7, " ", "") = 0, "NULL", H7)&"`.

Comment: I want h7 if it exists to be in between ' ' in my db. Would your formula accomplish that